# Able to access login page when user is still login in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have created login functionality using Laravel Default Auth, everything is working except i am able to access login page still when user is Login in application, i want to redirect user to dashboard url if user hit

> http://myapplication/login

it should automatically redirect to

> http://myapplication/dashboard

My controller code is :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = 'user/dashboard';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

> RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {

       if ((Auth::guard($guard)->check()) && $guard == 'web') {

            return redirect('/');
        } 

        if ((Auth::guard($guard)->check()) && $guard == 'admin') {

            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }


        return $next($request);


    }
```

> Auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Defaults
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
    | reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
    | as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
    |
    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Authentication Guards
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
    | Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
    | here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | Supported: "session", "token"
    |
    */

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Providers
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
    | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
    | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
    |
    | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
    | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
    | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
    |
    | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
    |
    */

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

        'admins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
        ],

        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Resetting Passwords
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
    | than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
    | separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
    |
    | The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
    | considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
    | they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
    |
    */

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Comment: $redirectTo = 'user/dashboard'; or $redirectTo = '/dashboard'; I am little bit confuse with your question(url of the dashboard) and with your code!

Comment: @SachinKumar: I have added code of RedirectIfAuthenticated.php file

Comment: No, my question is the $redirectTo property and their value in the LoginController class. as in middleware, it is "/dashboard" and in LoginController it is 'user/dashboard'

Comment: yes, In middleware i have also placed user/dashboard, but after removing $guard == 'web' my code is working, user is not able to see login page if he is already login, but how will i check here guard type i.e. whether it is for admin or normal user web

Comment: Your logic is incorrect I think. You should check the value of the $guard first and then call the Auth::guard($guard)->check() function. The if condition something like if ($guard == 'web' && Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {return redirect('/');} elseif(...)

Comment: But in my code, i want to know why i'm getting null value for guard when i login as a user and guard value is admin when login as admin

Comment: show your auth.php file and did you try by specify guard() function like "protected function guard(){return Auth::guard('guard_name');}" in LoginController?

Comment: I have edited my code, please check

Comment: Did you try with specifying this line in __construct function of LoginController.php "$this->middleware('guest:admin')->except('logout');" ?

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your `RedirectIfAuthenticated` Middleware like the following

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('user/dashboard');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what i have in RedirectIfAuthenticated :  if ((Auth::guard($guard)->check()) && $guard == 'web') {
        return redirect('/');   } but it is not working

Comment: I have two guards one for web and other is admin, but when i print guard it is null.

Comment: Try to delete every thing in the above `handle` method and keep only `return redirect('user/dashboard');` instruction and see what happens

Comment: if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {     return redirect('user/dashboard');    }, this is working, but i want to check guard too, because i have two guard one for admin and second one web for user.